# How to send command from server to client in mfc socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, mfc, asyncsocket

I transferred file from server to client... But I want to know how to send just command to client to just create file? Is this possible?

Comment: Depends on the protocol you're using for the communication. And if you don't have a protocol, then you might want to design one to use.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What I used to do is send message or files from server to client... This protocol is totally new to me... Could u pls show me how protocol looks like... Any tiny help would be great. Thank u